# How to log someone into Wi-Fi network with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, wifi

I know that the [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API), which has very limited [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=network%20information%20api), allows you to detect changes in the connection and access the connection type.

For example, it's possible to use the Android [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class to programmatically connect to a Wi-Fi network. I'm wondering if it's possible to do through a browser.

Is there any API that I could use to log someone into a Wi-Fi network or at least fill in the password on either a mobile browser or on Chrome?

Comment: Like Paul said, you can't. That would be a serious security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Mainstream browsers will not allow such access for security reasons. So, browsers cannot directly interact with system functionality.